# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 28: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, base64

I have a wav file that I converted to binary and then changed it to base64 using C# and then post that base64 string to a python flask API so I can decode it and change back the base64 string to a wav file so I can save in a folder, I am getting this error below:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 28: invalid start byte

Please see my code below:

```
public static void copy_to_watch_folder(string filepath, string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
                var destinationFolder = SSKAccess.mapped_dir_path;
                byte[] audio_file = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

                var s = Convert.ToBase64String(audio_file);

                string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Result = "OK", File = s, FileName = filename, token= SSKAccess.token }, Formatting.None);

                StringContent sC2 = new StringContent(jsonData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConnectionSetup.connectionStr);

                try
                {
                    var response = client.PostAsync("putWavFile", sC2).Result;

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Logs.WriteToFile($"{ DateTime.Now } : {response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Logs.WriteToFile($"HttpError : {exc.Message}");
                }

                //System.IO.File.Copy(filepath, $"{destinationFolder}{filename}", true);
            }
            catch (IOException copyError)
            {
                Logs.WriteToFile($"{DateTime.Now} - CopyError: {copyError.Message}");
            }

        }
```

My Python code looks like:

```
@app.route('/api/Call/putWavFile', methods=['POST'])
def PutWavFile():
    if not request.json or not 'token' in request.json: 
        abort(400)
    
    try:
        filename = request.json['FileName']
        binaryData = request.json['File'] 

        file_decoded = base64.decodebytes(binaryData.encode('utf-8').strip())

        _file = file_decoded.decode()
        path_to_save = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Watch', filename)
        with open(path_to_save, mode='wb') as f:
            f.write(file_decoded)

        return jsonify({"FileCreated": "Success"})
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"FileError: {str(exc)}")
        return jsonify( {"Error": f"{str(exc)}"} )
```

Please assist and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, the line causing this error is: 

file_decoded = base64.decodebytes(binaryData.encode('utf-8').strip())

Comment: I am not sure about python. However are you verified the payload looks as you would expect?

Comment: Yes, I did display it on my terminal getting the values using request.json['File'] and request.json['FileName'], and another thing is that if I remove the base64 encode and decode I do get a wav file but it can't play, so I assumed my byte got corrupted or something so I decided to use the base64 string to send the byte over to my API.

Comment: But where did you get the error? `file_decoded` is the binary wave file so `_file = file_decoded.decode()` should raise the error. Just remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks y'all for your assistance but finally I got the solution.
It turns out all I needed was the following line to decode the base64 string coming from my C# API call:

```
file_decoded = base64.b64decode(binaryData)
```

Thanks again for those who tried to assist.